# use admin theme to render modules pages

Tags: 7, theming, users

I want my custom module pages to be rendered using the admin theme, at the moment they only render using the admin theme for User 1 (see below).

I have a module called `mymodule` that defines many administrative views. It's setup in the following structure:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    return [
        'admin/content/foo'     => ['page callback' => 'handle_foo', /*other opts*/],
        'admin/content/foo/bar' => ['page callback' => 'handle_foobar', /*other opts*/], 
        /* list goes on*/
    ];
 }

 function handle_foo() {
    return ['#theme' => 'handle_foo'];
 }

 function theme_handle_foo() {
    /*database logic here, then return compiled html to be rendered. */
    return '<div> I am a foo!</div>';
 }
```

Say I have 2 users:

- User 1: All permissions available(including administration)
- User 2: 1 custom permission defined in the module

**When logged in as User 1**, all pages that follow `admin/*` are rendered with the drupal `admin_theme` including `mymodule` paths.

**When logged in as User 2** all of `mymodule` pages are rendered using the frontend theme.

I've tried using [hook_admin_paths](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7.x) but this doesn't work:

```
function mymodule_admin_paths() {
  return [
    'admin/content/foo'   => TRUE,
    'admin/content/foo/*' => TRUE,
    '/admin/content/foo'  => TRUE,
  ];
}
```

I have also read on here that any path that follows the `admin/*` convention should use the `admin_theme` by default which appears to be true for user 1 but not user 2.

My take on this is that I need to give user 2 some kind of permission, however I don't want them to be able to do anything other than login and access the paths set out in `mymodule`

*(I don't want to use 3rd party modules)*

Comment: What role user#2 does have ? Are you sure it has the permission "view the administration theme" ?

Comment: User 2 is a custom role with 1 permission. You are correct though I realised this just as you posted, thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions to this:

**Solution one**

Use `hook_custom_theme()`: [see hook_custom_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x)

```
function mymodule_custom_theme() {
 $use_admin = workout_when_you_want_to_use_admin(); //true or false
 if ($use_admin)
   return variable_get('admin_theme');
}
```

**Solution 2 (preferred)**

Ensure that the user account has the permission `View the administration theme` attached to their role.